# JavaScript variables used in new arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript variable defined as a new array in the following manner:

```
var myDaysComparisonData = new Array(['Mondays', 0], ['Tuesdays', 0], ['Wednesdays', 0], ['Thursdays', 0], ['Fridays', 0], ['Saturdays', 0], ['Sundays', 0]);
```

and also I have 7 globally defined variables called `myMondaysTotal`,`myTuesdaysTotal` and so on which holds the values that I want to replace the zeros in the upper array in the corresponding day of the week. What is the approach in this cases?

Comment: `... ['Mondays', myMondaysTotal], ...`

Comment: It sounds like an object would be more appropriate.

Comment: what is the need for that.

Comment: I use this array of arrays for generating a pie graph using a JavaScript library and is not working with `['Mondays', myMondaysTotal]`. My `myMondaysTotal` is defined like it should because if i use console.log is what is should (the number 3 in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is array of arrays, looks like it doesn't fit your goals.

Anyway to just replace the zero with variable, put the variable name instead the zero:

```
var myDaysComparisonData = new Array(['Mondays', myMondaysTotal], ['Tuesdays', myTuesdaysTotal], ...);
```

Better approach to this would be such associative array though:

```
var myDaysComparisonData = {'Mondays': myMondaysTotal, 'Tuesdays':  myTuesdaysTotal, ... };
```

If you really must use this structure and want to populate the internal arrays with values, you'll have to search for each item and assign its value, no elegant solution:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myDaysComparisonData.length; i++) {
    var curArray = myDaysComparisonData[i];
    switch (curArray[0]) {
        case "Mondays":
            curArray[1] = myMondaysTotal;
            break;
        case "Tuesdays":
            curArray[1] = myTuesdaysTotal;
            break;
        //........
    }
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/e5bVa/).

Comment: I need to use this kind of array of arrays in order to suits my needs and is not working with just putting the variables there, I've tried this before with no success...

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<7;i++) 
    myDaysComparisonData[i][1] = window["my"+myDaysComparisonData[i][0]+"Total"];
```

Answer (score -3):

I think this is what you mean?

```
myDaysComparisonData['Mondays'] = myMondaysTotal;
```